# Magento 2 - not able to find some functions

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, magento-2.0

I was working on the shipping part, but I found that some functions' declaration can not be found in the code repository. For example, in the 1000th line of

> app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php

```
$shippingRates = $result->getAllRates();
```

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php#L1000

I searched the whole mangento 2 repository, but I could not find something like

```
public function getAllRates(){ //....}
```

Is there any mechanism in Magento 2 that will auto generate functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getAllRates` method is not a direct method as you assumed, understand that it does not process anything it is a simple getter.

What happens in the `app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php` is that first, this line is called:

```
$result = $this->_rateCollector->create()->collectRates($request)->getResult();
```

The `collectRates` method is called, this method is implemented by every carrier model that implements the `RateCollectorInterface` interface.

This `collectRates` method returns a `Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result` object which is retrieved by the `getResult()` method.

Then the `getAllRates()` method is called from `Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result`:

```
public function getAllRates()
{
    return $this->_rates;
}
```

The `_rates` variable is set via the `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory` directly in the carrier model, most of the time with code that looks like this:

```
$rate = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
$rate->setCarrier($this->_code);
$rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
$rate->setMethod($method);
$rate->setMethodTitle($this->getCode('method', $method));
$rate->setCost($costArr[$method]);
$rate->setPrice($price);
$result->append($rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in `Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result` around line 90:

```
    /**
     * Return all quotes in the result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllRates()
    {
        return $this->_rates;
    }
```

This is what you are looking for.

Anyway, in Magento2 there are some automatically created classes and methods, but not for this kind of functions. Mainly for plugins and factories.

Hope it helps.